# Should this sentence be included in the Executive Summary?

Tags: technical-writing

I found some examples of good and poor example of executive summaries [here](http://unilearning.uow.edu.au/report/4bi1.html). Everything seems fine but in one of them, they included this sentence -

> "All calculations can be found in the appendices"

One of my teammates complains that everyone knows where to find the calculations, so why should someone put this sentence in their executive summary?

My question is: does everyone really know where to find the calculations even if it is not mentioned anywhere? Is it okay to put this sentence in the executive summary of a technical report?

Comment: It would depend on what kinds of calculations, and the type of document. And it's also difficult to say if a sentence is needed for a hypothetical piece of text. (I assume we're talking about executive summaries in general and not about a specific one.)

Comment: Of course it's OK. There's no need to hide information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your teammate: Leave it out. Keep the executive summary as short and succinct as possible. It is understood that the rest of the report contains the details. You could make it clear where to find the calculations by using descriptive titles in the table of contents:

> *Appendix C: Supporting Calculations ...... Page 65*